# To display chips or buttons based on JSON property value in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

My **JSON** file looks like this:
**customers.json**

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Customer One",
        "status": "Open"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Customer Two",
        "status": "Active"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Customer Three",
        "status": "Open"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Customer Four",
        "status": "Closed"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Customer Five",
        "status": "Active"
    }
]
```

As shown in the above code there is an property called `status`, Based on this property(status) value in the template i want to display:

- Must use  `chip` for  **Open** status.
- **Green** button with some text for **Active** status.
- **Red**  button with some text for **Closed** status.

  > NOTE: **And the text can be anything not the property(staus) value**:

[Reference PIc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYwCd.png)

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-vtqj2u?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    <div *ngFor="let customer of customers">
        <div>{{customer.name}}</div>
        <mat-chip-list *ngIf="customer.status ==='Open';else elseBlock">
          <mat-chip class="open">This customer service is {{customer.status}}</mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
        <ng-template #elseBlock>
          <button [ngClass]="customer.status ==='Active'? 'active': 'close'">This customer service is {{customer.status}}</button>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
```

In css:

```
.active {
  background-color:green;
  color:white
}

.close {
  background-color:red;
  color:white
}
.open {
  background-color:gray;
  color:white
}
```

[image: Output of above code]

Comment: getting this error:  `Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)`

Comment: Can i show chip(material component) for the status `open` as i  shown in the image?

Comment: For the other status i,e (Active & Clased) button is fine.

Comment: Still left with one more requirement: Status text can be anything which i can give, It should no be the property value like(Active,Closed.Open..).Please see the updated image.

Comment: Did you meant to add a message along with property as "This customer service is "?

Comment: Please add the line  'This customer service is' before {{customer.status}}

Comment: I don't want to show any status property value i,e Active,Closed,... , based on status i want to show my own texts inside `chips/button`.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same kind of issue. We did using the below logic

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let btn of actions">
   <ng-container *ngIf="btn.action === 'APPROVE'">
      <button *ngIf="!getRunCreditEngineCondition()" [class]="btn.buttonClass" (click)="clickAction(btn.action)" style="white-space: normal;">{{btn.label}}</button>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="btn.action === 'RUNCREDITENGINE'">
       <button *ngIf="getRunCreditEngineCondition()" [class]="btn.buttonClass " (click)="clickAction(btn.action)" style="white-space:normal;">{{btn.label}}</button>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="btn.action !== 'RUNCREDITENGINE' && btn.action !== 'APPROVE'">
       <button [class]="btn.buttonClass" (click)="clickAction(btn.action)" style="white-space: normal;">{{btn.label}}</button>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```